# Highlighting search results in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to have Excel highlight search results, or specific text that you're looking for?  I really appreciate these features as they are in Firefox and IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled your demand and found out that you can use a macro to do this.

```
Sub FindHighlight()
Dim tempCell As Range, Found As Range, sTxt, FoundRange, Response As Integer
Set Found = Range("A1")
sTxt = InputBox(prompt:="Enter value for search", Title:="VoG's Finder")
If sTxt = "" Then Exit Sub
Set tempCell = Cells.Find(what:=sTxt, After:=Found)
If tempCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox prompt:="Not found", Title:="VoG's Finder"
Exit Sub
Else
Set Found = tempCell
Set FoundRange = Found
End If
Do
Set tempCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=Found)
If Found.Row >= tempCell.Row And Found.Column >= tempCell.Column Then Exit Do
Set Found = tempCell
Set FoundRange = Application.Union(FoundRange, Found)
Loop
FoundRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Response = MsgBox(prompt:="Clear highlighting", Title:="VoG's Finder", Buttons:=vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
If Response = vbOK Then FoundRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

> When the macro runs it will highlight
>   the found cells and give the option to
>   clear the highlighting. If you want to
>   temporarily keep the highlighting
>   click Cancel. Then, to clear the
>   formatting later on, run the same
>   search and click OK.

[Click here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/index.cfm?action=showthread&threadid=305437&forumid=1) to view the source.